# how to remove special characterics in regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:`"afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [+12]xxx!"`

I wish to remove all characters except numbers 47 and 12. I have tried with several different regex combinations for hours but I just cant figure it out.

```
import re

def integers_in_brackets(s):
res =[]
res = re.findall(r'[+-]?\b\d+\b',s)

print(res)

for i in range(0, len(res)):
    res[i] = int(res[i])

return res
```

the function should return [47, 12]

Comment: `function should return [47, 12]` is not matching with title: `how to remove special characterics in regex python`

Comment: It would be easier to find the 12s and 47s and join the result back into a string. `''.join(re.findall('12|47', s))`. (With some adjustment to match only complete words 12 and 47.)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should match your requirements

```
(?<=[\[\s\+])\b\d+\b(?=[\]\s])
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this regex:

```
"\[(?P<value>\s*\+?\d+\s*)\]"g
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/Xnk2V9/1)

Explanation:

- allows patterns like [ +22 ], [ 22 ], [+22], [22]
- rejects patterns like [ ++22 ], [+-22], [-22], [22+]

#### Python

```py
import re

test_str = "afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [12]xxx [++2222]cxx  [ -+12 ]yy [1 2]xxx!"

arr = re.findall("\[(?P<value>\s*\+?\d+\s*)\]", test_str)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use re.findall to get the digits between square brackets with an optional leading plus or minus sign:

```
\[\s*[+-]?(\d+)\s*]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `\s*` Match optional whitspace chars
- `[+-]?` Match an optional `+` or `-`
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits (which will be returned by *re.findall*)
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `]` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JARAyP/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"\[\s*[+-]?(\d+)\s*]"
s = "afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [+12]xxx!"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['47', '12']
```